# Como colocar som em c++?

Tags: c++

ainda sou novo com programação e queria colocar o som do super Mario dentro de um projeto da faculdade, como faço para que ele possa funcionar?

**Código:**

```
int certo=0,errado=0,certoVF=0,certoA=0; 
char resposta,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7; 
int nivel,v,x; 

printf ("\t| 0 - SAIR DO GAME |\n"); 
printf ("\t| 1 - JOGAR TODOS OS NÍVEIS |\n"); 
printf ("\t| 2 - JOGAR NIVEL FÁCIL - SOMENTE O NIVEL FÁCIL |\n"); 
printf ("\t| 3 - JOGAR NIVEL MÉDIO - SOMENTE O NIVEL MÉDIO |\n"); 
printf ("\t| 4 - JOGAR NIVEL DIFÍCIL - SOMENTE O NIVEL DIFÍCIL |\n");
printf ("\t Oque deseja fazer? "); 
scanf ("%d",&nivel);
```

Comment: Qual seu SO? Já tem algum código ou pesquisou algo?

Comment: windows, eu achei o codigo do som, porém na hora de colocar no código do jogo não deu certo

Comment: Se possível edite a questão adicionando o trecho de código onde insere a função que chama o som, seguido do erro (se tiver dado algum). Daí poderemos dar um direcionamento :)

Comment: eu adcionei bem no inicio, tentei usar o for e logo após o codigo do menu do jogo, em seguida os beep para fazer o som. so que ele toca a musica e não vai pra frente com as perguntas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060601/make-sounds-beep-with-c) existe uma pergunta similar, sendo a resposta marcada como correta, o uso da função `Beep`, da seguinte forma:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h> // header do WinApi

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    Beep(523,500); // 523 hertz (C5) por 500 milissegundos (0,5 segundos)
    cin.get(); // espera tocar o som
    return 0; 
}
```

Documentação da [função `Beep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) caso queira ver.

Comment: ah sim, muito obrigado

Comment: int certo=0,errado=0,certoVF=0,certoA=0;
 char resposta,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7;
 int nivel,v,x;
 printf ("\t|  0 - SAIR DO GAME                                    |\n");
 printf ("\t|  1 - JOGAR TODOS OS NÍVEIS                           |\n");
 printf ("\t|  2 - JOGAR NIVEL FÁCIL   - SOMENTE O NIVEL FÁCIL     |\n");            
 printf ("\t|  3 - JOGAR NIVEL MÉDIO   - SOMENTE O NIVEL MÉDIO   |\n");
 printf ("\t|  4 - JOGAR NIVEL DIFÍCIL - SOMENTE O NIVEL DIFÍCIL   |\n")
 printf ("\t Oque deseja fazer? ");                                            
 scanf ("%d",&nivel);

Comment: ai quando escolhesse um valor diferente de 0  a musica ficaria tocando. Tem algum modo de fazer isso?

Comment: @Murilo, editei sua pergunta e adicionei o código, no comentário fica complicado de ler e entender.

Comment: ah sim, muito obrigado :)

Comment: E respondendo sua pergunta, você faz um `if` e verifica se é diferente de `0`, se sim você executa o código que mostrei na resposta, faça o teste e veja se funciona.

Comment: aham, vou tentar aqui, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @Murilo algum progresso?

Comment: eu e uns colegas da faculdade colocamos para tocar e depois iniciar, como somos novos em programação, não temos o conhecimento tão amplo para fazer com que duas tarefas sejam executadas ao mesmo tempo, mas foi de grande ajuda a explicação.

Comment: Okay, se puder fecha a pergunta, pra não ficar em aberto, só clicar na seta ao lado do voto, na pergunta.